# Что не так со скачанным через pip модулем Python?

Tags: python, pip

Пытаюсь установить модуль `reactpy`, который беру с репозитория GitHub. Использовал команду `pip install git+https://github.com/reactive-python/reactpy`. Получил итог, что *библиотека установлена успешно*. Причем библиотека `scripts`.

Когда в тестовом коде попробовал импортировать `reactpy`, поймал ошибку с отсутствием модуля. Команда `pip list` его также не показала.

Следом скачал архивный файл и через команду `pip3 install .` попробовал его установить: опять не помогло. Модуля не появилось.

Что не так делаю?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что он так вообще должен поставиться? В документации такой способ вроде не описан https://reactpy.dev/docs/guides/getting-started/installing-reactpy.html#installing-reactpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В описании модуля на https://pypi.org/project/reactpy/
написано, что для установки модуля надо выполнить:

```
pip install reactpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы работаете в IDE, то иногда можно вручную проверять библиотеку(на скрине) и в пару кликов установить её в нужное виртуальное окружение, если вдруг через pip что-то не получилось.

[image: ответ на вопрос]

Мне порой помогает, особенно, когда хочется сначала узнать номер последней версии библиотеки, без предварительной установки через pip и гугления)

Ну и можно сразу увидеть всех похожие/аналогичные библиотеки.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку с функционалом PyCharm